# Is there a mathematical way of finding b, given a to the power of b and a?

Tags: exponentiation, integers

For example, we have $a^b = 256$ and $a = 2$.

Can I find $b = 8$ without trying all possible values of $b$ ?

Comment: Are you familiar with logarithms?

Comment: I am, but I didn't think about it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! $b=\log_2256$ - a calculator will give this result.

Comment: Thanks, my question was really dumb finally...

Comment: No worries, it's good to ask when you're not sure, sometimes a nice method can solve a question easily:)

Comment: Actually you don't even need a calculator if you realize that $256$ is a power of $2$ (just keep dividing it by two and you'll always get an even number until you reach $2$ itself), and that $\log_2 256$ is *that number $x$ such that $2^x = 256$*.